# Are the elliptical arc-curves broken when drawing svg:s in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, svg

I'm trying to draw an ellipse on a google map using svg-shapes.

The following path (a star) works fine:

```
var goldStar = {
    path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
    fillColor: "yellow",
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: "gold",
    strokeWeight: 14
};
```

But thisone(an eliptical arc) does not show at all.

```
var elipticalarc = {
    path: 'M 0,0 a20,10 0 1,1 100,100',
    fillColor: "yellow",
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: "gold",
    strokeWeight: 14
};
```

You can se both paths working by replacing the path with the d-attribute in the following link:

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_path

Comment: Is your variable name really two words?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps I should have made an answer out of that comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was just really tiny.